Looker studio Duplicate date issue
I have column thatI need only month and year when I use this formula : FORMAT_DATETIME("%b ,%Y", Close Date)
I am getting duplicate values can you please help me to delete the duplicates and just have unique date values
This is looker studio
Tried creating another column and get the count but that didnt work
